# Unity. Function call after a certain period of time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

How can I make an object invisible (or just delete) after a certain period of time? 
Use NGUI.

My example (for changes):

```
public class scriptFlashingPressStart : MonoBehaviour  
{   
    public GameObject off_Logo;
    public float dead_logo = 1.5f;

    void OffLogo()  
    {       
        off_Logo.SetActive(false);  
    }

    //function onclick button
    //remove item after a certain time after pressing ???
    void press_start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("OffLogo", dead_logo , ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI - if you put 4 spaces at the start of a line.. the code becomes syntax highlighted. I have done it for you on this question.

Comment: Wrong Unity in your third tag sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Invoke rather than InvokeRepeating.
check Invoke function [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)

```
 public class scriptFlashingPressStart : MonoBehaviour  
    {   
        public GameObject off_Logo;
        public float dead_logo = 1.5f;
        bool pressed = false;

    void OffLogo()  
    {       
       //do anything(delete or invisible)
        off_Logo.SetActive(false);
         pressed = false;  
    }

   //use Invoke rather than InvokeRepeating
    void press_start()
    {
        if(!pressed)
        {
          pressed = true;
          Invoke("OffLogo", dead_logo);
        }
        else
        {
          Debug.Log("Button already pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
StartCoroutine(SomeFunctionAfterSomeTime);

IEnumerator SomeFunctionAfterSomeTime()
{
    ... //Your own logic
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(SomeTime);
}
```

Comment: What library uses IEnumerator?

Comment: @easy_peasy, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @easy_peasy check out http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Coroutines.html

Comment: would you need to 1st do the wait and then 2nd add your logic ? (if you wanted to add a delay _before_ your code)

Comment: @Nande No need.

Answer (score 1):

You can destroy an object in a given time by simply calling Destroy.

```
public static void Destroy(Object obj, float t = 0.0F);
```

Parameters

- **obj**  The object to destroy.
- **t**    The optional amount of time to delay
  before destroying the object.

See http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html